# Finding limits with substitution

Tags: calculus, limits, probability-limit-theorems

$\lim_{x\to0+}(\sinh(x))^{1/x}$

I started by setting $y=\frac{\sinh(x)}{x}$ and taking the natural logarithm of both sides and trying to solve the limit for $ln(y)$ but I got stuck trying to solve $\lim_{x\to0+}\frac{\ln(\sinh(x))}{x}$. Any ideas? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: This is not a problematic limit. $\sinh(x)$ approaches $0$, and the exponent approaches $\infty$, hence the function clearly approaches $0$.

Comment: @Teddy Thanks for your answer, but I thought $0^{\infty}$ was not defined.

Comment: Well, $1^\infty$ is a problematic form, in the sense that it's not clear what the limit is. The form $0^\infty$ simply goes to $0$.

Comment: @JoeS The point here is that if $|x|<1$, then $x^n \to 0$ for $n\to\infty$. Thus, if the sequence $x_n$ goes to zero, then $x_n^n$ goes to zero even faster.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}(\sinh(x))^{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}e^{\frac{1}{x}\ln(\sinh(x))}$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{1}{x}=+\infty $$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\ln(\sinh(x))=-\infty $$

so $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} e^{\frac{1}{x}\ln(\sinh(x))}=e^{-\infty}=0$$